# What latency do you expect when serving static files?

Tags: performance

I'm running some latency measurements using [Web Page Speed Test](http://www.webpagetest.org/) on a static javascript file. I compared hosting the file at four locations: [Host Monster](http://www.hostmonster.com/), [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Amazon Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), and [Heroku Static Sites](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-on-heroku).

The results I'm getting are around 240ms-390ms, the worst being Host Monster. The tests were run from the default Web Page Speed Test data center at Dulles, VA, USA. The S3 zone I used was "US standard".

My question is - isn't 240ms+ latency a bit too much for just serving a javascript file (33kb minified before gzip - Host Monster and Heroku have out-of-the-box gzip, it's a bit less seamless for Amazon Web Services do not so I didn't enable it for this test). What top latency should I expect when serving a static 30kb file from the US to the US?

How can we to the sub 100ms latency zone?

**Edit**

Here is a sample latency breakdown from Web Page Speed Test on Amazon CloudFront:

```
DNS Lookup: 49 ms
Initial Connection: 59 ms
Time to First Byte: 123 ms
Content Download: 28 ms
```

Comment: I just re-found these posts about Stack Exchange's CDN - they're seeing sub-100ms from Amazon and other hosts. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90073/help-us-test-the-advantages-of-using-a-cdn http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90921/help-us-test-cdns-round-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue was with me using the default setting on Web Page Speed Test. Try using FIOS under Connection Settings to get a more real measurement.

Answer (score 0):

i can clearly say that the website you are using is not accurate. use firefox install firebug and test the speed yourself. i live in Turkey and the file i am downloading from USA took total 173 ms. you can delete all history cached data for more accuracy. i used my own host for test. file downloaded first time.